# Removing index.php using new supported method results in contact form returning to weird page

Tags: expressionengine

I have created an htaccess form and it only contains :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

->which is shown in the latest user guide as the new supported way of removing index.php.

All is good and my contact form is working fine - except after the form submits, shows the message and then redirects it is not redirecting back to the homepage I have specified (which is currently testsite7) but it is actually redirecting to "testsite7/_mp3" I have no idea why it is showing this? that is a folder on my server with the music files in it.

My site is on an addon domain and the EE install is above root.

Any ideas !

Comment: Best to move this to the EE StackExchange site? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, not sure why it would be redirecting to that specific folder, and I don't see why that code would be causing it. It may be worth trying a different .htaccess method to just narrow down what the problem may be. This is one that we use on all our large sites and has always worked well. Maybe give it a go:

```
# turn on mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# make sure index.php is always removed from url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# make sure we don't have a trailing slash unless it's a directory
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# make sure requests are routed through index.php but not in url this helps certain addons.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```